# pass variable from php loop to javascript function as argument

Tags: javascript, php

The job should be easy, but i miss something...
I read a variable from database and i need a div to change color based on the variable value.

I'll appreciate also ideas to make the script shorter.
Thanks

```
 <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function setColor(status){
       var a= status;
       if (a == "tag1") {
       document.getElementById("status").style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
                       } ; 
       elseif (a == "tag2") {
       document.getElementById("status").style.backgroundColor = "black"; 
                       } ; 
   }

</script>
```

...

```
<?php
$general=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM general ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 200;");
$n=mysql_numrows($general);
$i=0;
while($i<$n)    {
$status=mysql_result($general,$i,"status");
echo '<div id="row">
<div class="celln" id="status" name="status">'.$status.'</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     setColor("<?php echo $status; ?>");
  </script>
</div>';

$i++;
};
?>
```

Comment: `Identifiers in HTML must be unique`, You are creating them in loop hence multiple elements will have same id.

Comment: remove semicolon ';' inside a query  $general=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM general ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 200");

Comment: you can't get the row number unless you pass the **link** to your **mysql_numrows** , and you should try to pass the variacle to **document.getElementById()** insted of the string **'status'**

Comment: assign a css class, while echoing variable just echo the class out on argument?

Comment: @MarkNg see my answer

Comment: ya, @mplungjan answer are pretty straightforward,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
<style>
.tag1 { background-color:red }
.tag2 { background-color:black }
</style>
...
echo '<div class="celln '.$status.'" id="status">'.$status.'</div>';
```

Divs do not have name attributes by the way

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Saty, the `mysql_*` suite of functions are now deprecated so either mysqli or PDO are the way forward.

Unless there wasa particular need to use Javascript to set the background colour of each div according to some value from the db why not use css combined with PHP?

```
<style>
    .red{color:white;background:red;}
    .blue{color:white;background:blue;}
    .white{color:black;background:white;}
    .black{color:yellow;background:black;}
</style>

<?php

    $conn=new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    $sql='select * from `general` order by `id` desc limit 0, 200;';
    $res=$conn->query( $conn, $sql );

    if( $res ){

        function getclass($status){
            switch( $status ){
                case 'tag1': return 'red';
                case 'tag2': return 'black';
                case 'tag3':return 'blue';
                default: return 'white';
            }
        }

        $i=0;
        while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
            $i++;
            $class=getclass( $rs->status );

            echo '
                <div id="row'.$i.'">
                    <div class="celln '.$class.'">'.$status.'</div>
                </div>';
        }
    }
    $conn->close();

?>
```